# How to remove special chars EXACTLY in .net 2.0, no linq is provided

Tags: .net, string, char, trim, remove-if

I must to use .NET 2.0 and I have no Linq support here, also...

I've tried to trim chars using Remove() and Trim() functions like:

```
  string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  string result = header.Trim( new Char[] { ' ', '-'} ));
```

But for the `Trim()` sample, the result is the same as `string guid` ( they are just equal ).

I've done such function, but I want to use correctly functions from the sealed `String class`.

```
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
        string result = String.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < guid.Length; i++)
        {
            if (guid[i] != '-') result += guid[i];
        }
```

But it looks like plain C style and I want to use exactly String function. Where did I fail with Trim() and Remove().

Don't forget, that I can't use Linq or higher version of .net 2.0, so the question is on the lower level...

Answer (score 3):

```
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"); //generate it the right way
```

or

```
result = guid.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "");
```

Don't use a Regex. It is unnecessarily complex and unnecessarily slow. It is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could always use regex

```
 system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(guid.NewGuid(),"[\s|-]","");
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but I'm still confused why does not Trim() work?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar in what place did you see that I'm asking about strongly and exactly about 1 thing? try to read again or I may send you some glasses via real mail not web one

Comment: @mikeTheLiar my apologies for being evil and that have argued at you... I have chat in C++ room there were only ridicule about my problem, seems to be that I'm used to the normal communication because innormal chat speeches , sorry again

Comment: @OlegOrlov no problem, it's often difficult to understand a person's true intentions over the internet. My comment was directed at the answerer, not you.